# Using cURL for Amazon Associates reports... possible?

Tags: php, curl

I've got a couple of affiliate sites and would like to bring together the earnings reports from several Amazon sites into one place, for easier viewing and analysis.

I get the impression that cURL can be used to get external webpage content, which I could then scrape to obtain the necessary info. However, I've hit a wall in trying to log in to the Associates reports using cURL.

Has anyone done this and do you have any advice?

Comment: Does amazon offer a webservice call to get this data?

Comment: I can't find any such webservice. I know it must be possible to get to this data in some automated way, having seen an iphone app that does it. However, I don't know how they did it.

Comment: Hello Don...

I was wondering if you managed to figure out how to deal with the session variable in grabbing reports via CURL?  Stumped by it.  Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Alas no, I am stuck at the same place. I'd love to know how to do this.

Comment: this is even more difficult now that amazon have updated their login page with all sorts of CSFR protection... come on amazon, give us a webservice for this! Or at least some automated report emails so we can parse it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am working on an open-source project called [PHP-OARA](http://php-oara.affjet.com/) it's allows you to get your data from the different networks, it's part of the [AffJet Project](http://www.affjet.com/).

We have solved the problem with Amazon(it wasn't easy) and a PHP class is available to get your data from your associate account.If you like it you can even co-operate to do it better.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this, but youll need to make use of cookies with curl: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-curl-cookies/ But id be willing to bet some cash that Amazon offers an API to get the data you want, although the last time i dealt with their web services it was a nightmare but proably because i was using the PHP SOAP extension and Amazon SOAP API.

Comment: I've tried looking into using curl with cookies, but I'm stumped by what I think might be a session variable generated by Amazon. As far as I can find, there doesn't seem to be any API access to this information, so I'm pretty sure you'd lose that bet.

However I'd love to be proved wrong on that point.

Comment: "As far as I can find, there doesn't seem to be any API access to this information, so I'm pretty sure you'd lose that bet. However I'd love to be proved wrong on that point." I dont use AS much.. whats the name/title of the interface application a human user uses to view this data and the name of the "account type"? Maybe I can prove you wrong if i know what im looking for :-)

Comment: Hmm. I'm not sure I understand the question. The reports are found at http://associates.amazon.com/ and http://associates.amazon.co.uk, etc.

Comment: Here's an app for the iphone that manages it somehow: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/affiliate-reports-for-amazon/id360611910?mt=8

Comment: If you're still around prodigitalson, I'd be willing to bet $20 that there is no API access for this information. I'd happily lose.

Comment: Yeah i couldnt find anything. Im going to assume that iPhone app is doing precisely what you tried to do... that is use a library like cURL to login and then scrape reports for data and present it in its own interface. Its a shame the app isnt open source you could disect and translate the code from *C to whatever.

Comment: Thank you for looking, I really appreciate it. I'll keep poking away at the curl idea for now.